# Authentication mechanishim in publish

Tags: authentication, aem, sling

Experts,

I have to implement authentication mechanism same as how author instance works. For example, if any user request for any page http:somehost:someport/content/geometrixx/en.html then system should open the page http:somehost:someport/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/account/login.html and only after successful login sling should redirect to required page.

I looked into Login Selector Authentication Handler and Sling Authentication Service but it seems there is no configuration here. Could you please let me know your thoughts on how to proceed on this? How it will be possible without CUG and how similer mechanism works in Author instance?

Comment: did you get the solution to your problem. I have been looking for configuration of form based authentication myself from last two days. Have looked into a lot of areas but haven't been able to figure out anything.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to redirect to the login page if the user is unauthenticated then you will have to do 2 things.
1. Go to /system/console and navigate to the Configuration. Select "Apache Sling Authentication Service". Disable Anonymous access.
2. Go to /libs/cq/security/config.publish/LoginSelectorHandler - Change the login page to the page you want.

Answer (score 1):

Goto http:somehost:someport/useradmin search for anonymous user. click on the anonymous user -> click on permission tab -> remove the read permission on the path that shouldn't be accessible to anonymous users.